# If a sorcery causes a creature of mine to deal damage to target creature or player, do I have to then tap my creature?

Tags: magic-the-gathering

If I were to cast a sorcery like [Rabid Bite](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Rabid%20Bite), does that tap my creature after the damage is dealt or can I use it in my attack phase too? Can I still use it to defend? What about the sorcery [Prey Upon](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Prey%20Upon)?

Comment: is there some reason to assume they would get tapped?

Answer (score 9):

Neither effects cause your creature to become tapped.

Tapping a creature to attack is a specific part of the creature attacking and actually has nothing to do with the damage dealt.  This is the reason why Vigilance works the way it does.  There is nothing intrinsic about tapping and damage being dealt.  Rabid Bite would explicitly have to say

> "Tap target creature you control.  It deals damage equal to its power to target creature you don't control."

Specifically with Fight, you can read from the [Innistrad](https://magic.wizards.com/en/articles/archive/feature/mechanics-2011-08-28) release article which explicitly says that the creatures do not become tapped.

> For a creature to fight another creature, each deals damage equal to its power to the other. A few finer points:
>
> - The damage is dealt simultaneously, and it is dealt by the creatures themselves, so abilities like deathtouch, lifelink, and infect will work as normal.
> - Damage dealt while fighting is not combat damage, so abilities like first strike won't have any effect.
> - **Fighting doesn't cause the creatures to become tapped.**
> - Only creatures can fight.
> - No more than two creatures can fight.
> - If a creature somehow fights itself, it will deal damage to itself equal to its power twice simultaneously.

Comment: Note that in one era of MtG, a tapped blocking creature would not deal damage.  This has long been no longer the case.

Comment: To expand upon this answer, in Magic, unlike in many other card games (looking at you, Yugioh), the cards do what they say they do and nothing else.  This is becoming less and less the case as the number of keywords increase, and Planeswalker as a creature type is something of a disaster in terms of user experience, but in general it's still pretty safe to assume that a card does what it says and does not do what it doesn't say.

Comment: @Ertai87 That's total BS. Every keyword action, including deal damage, has a rule definition, so you have to look up the definition of dealing damage in the rules to know what it does. The definition of dealing damage could include tapping the source of the damage. It doesn't, but it could. You have to look up the rule definition to know. You can't just read the card as you say. In fact,  dealing damage does something like 7 different things!